# Weird performance issue for numba.jit function calling another numba.jit function

Tags: python, python-3.x, numba

I noticed some weird performance results when a parent function calls a child function, and both functions are `numba.jit` compiled. Can anyone explain this behaviour (code below)? More importantly, is there anyway around this problem?

**Why this matters:** Suppose I'm writing a long, complicated function which I hope to speed-up using `numba.jit` compilation. It makes sense to wrap sub-procedures into child functions; which are then called by the parent function. If both parent and child functions need just-in-time compilation, then I'd run into this problem (i.e. performance drops for no obvious reason).

**Code:**

```
import time
import numpy
import numba


@numba.jit('void(int64[:])', nopython=True)
def bubble_sort(array):
    n = len(array)
    for _ in range(n):
        for i in range(n):
            if i+1 < n and array[i] > array[i+1]:
                temp = array[i]
                array[i] = array[i+1]
                array[i+1] = temp


@numba.jit('void(int64[:])')
def nested_with_jit(array):
    bubble_sort(array)


def nested_without_jit(array):
    bubble_sort(array)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 50000
    array = numpy.arange(n).astype(numpy.int64)

    print('bubble_sort(array)')
    for i in range(5):
        start = time.time()
        bubble_sort(array)
        end = time.time()
        print('\t#{:d}: ~{:.4f} seconds'.format(i, end - start))

    print('nested_with_jit(array)')
    for i in range(5):
        start = time.time()
        nested_with_jit(array)
        end = time.time()
        print('\t#{:d}: ~{:.4f} seconds'.format(i, end - start))

    print('nested_without_jit(array)')
    for i in range(5):
        start = time.time()
        nested_without_jit(array)
        end = time.time()
        print('\t#{:d}: ~{:.4f} seconds'.format(i, end - start))
```

**Output:**

> ```
> bubble_sort(array)
>     #0: ~1.9890 seconds
>     #1: ~1.9710 seconds
>     #2: ~1.9840 seconds
>     #3: ~1.9830 seconds
>     #4: ~1.9880 seconds
> nested_with_jit(array)
>     #0: ~2.4730 seconds
>     #1: ~2.4690 seconds
>     #2: ~2.4620 seconds
>     #3: ~2.4640 seconds
>     #4: ~2.4380 seconds
> nested_without_jit(array)
>     #0: ~1.9780 seconds
>     #1: ~1.9880 seconds
>     #2: ~1.9880 seconds
>     #3: ~1.9910 seconds
>     #4: ~1.9880 seconds
> ```

Comment: Probably this can be useful. I just run code above on my machine (i7-8700K) with llvmlite-0.29.0, numba-0.45.1, python 3.6.8, ubuntu 18.10. ~1.9178 for bubble_sort, ~1.4993 for nested_with_jit, and ~1.9202 for nested_without_jit. So, probably nested functions is not an issue for modern versions of numba

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be seeing is some small overhead of type checking and dispatch, although for some reason on my machine (OSX py2.7 numba 0.36.1), I'm seeing a smaller overhead (1.45 sec for calling `bubble_sort` directly and 1.63 sec for calling it with `nested_with_jit`). If I use `numba.jit(nopython=True)` with no explicit type, on both `bubble_sort` and `nested_with_jit`, the difference basically disappears.

Comment: It does not seem reasonable for "type checking and dispatch" to consume 0.2 seconds (or 0.5 seconds on OP's system).  At 3 GHz, that's 600-1500 million clock cycles!

Comment: When I look at the output of `inspect_types`, the only difference I can see if that the version of the function that specifies types marks the arrays as `A` (any layout), whereas the one that allows numba to use type inference based on the inputs it's `C` (continuous memory layout). When in doubt, ask on the Numba gitter and maybe a developer might have some insight https://gitter.im/numba/numba